# *ngIf causing browser to crash

Tags: angular

In one of my templates I have a condition as below:

```
<span *ngIf="(authService.isAuthenticated() | async)"> .. </span>
```

The isAuthenticated() function is defined as below:

```
 isAuthenticated() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        resolve(true);
        this.updateToken();
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }

    });
  }
```

Why does this cause the browser to crash ?

Comment: No JavaScript code, as incorrect as it could be, should crash the browser. If the browser crashes, it's a bug in the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet what?!!? That's totally incorrect. There are many ways to crash a browser with JS. The most simple: `for (let i=0; i>0; i++) {`. Sometimes you get to kill the process, most of the time it doesn't matter cos you are gonna have to restart the browser anyway.

Comment: @edzillion that's a noop. If it crashes your browser, it's even worse than I imagine. But even with `>=` rather than `>`, to make an infinite loop, my browser doesn't crash. The tab becomes unresponsive (which IMO, should also count as a bug), and the other ones keep working fine. That's far from being a crash.

Comment: Well I guess you don't have a million tabs open then! Most of the time when I crash a browser like this it won't come back. What you say might be true on an abstract level, but it is just plain false in the real world.

Comment: Assuming you're using chrome, open your task manager/activity monitor or whatever, find the chrome helper process consuming 100% of CPU, kill it, then close the tab. I just did that with your (fixed) example without problem. And chrome doesn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute a service method directly from a component.

Define a boolean variable inside your component.ts and set it based on the service value.

```
 isAuthenticated = false;
```

and change the variable by calling your service. Update your HTML as,

```
<span *ngIf="isAuthenticated"> .. </span>
```

This how you inject your authService to your component,

```
constructor(public authService: yourAuthService) { }
```

Comment: I think you *could*, if you had `constructor(public authService: ...) { }`. It's probably not a good idea, though.